# For x in array breaking after just one iteration python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

I'm studying about graphs and python isn't working as it should on one thing.

I'm writing the removeVertex function like this:

```
def remove_vertex(self, vertex):
    cities = self.adjacencyList[vertex] # Cities is an array ["mexico", "japan"]
    for city in cities: 
        self.remove_edge(vertex, city)
    self.adjacencyList.pop(vertex, None)
    return True
```

Basically im looping through the adjacency list of a vertex and removing all the edges of it, my graph is unweighted and undirectional.

This is my full code for the class:

```
class Graph:
def __init__(self):
    self.adjacencyList = {}

def add_vertex(self, name):
    if name not in self.adjacencyList.keys():
        self.adjacencyList[name] = []
        return True
    else:
        return False

def add_edge(self, vertex_a, vertex_b):
    self.adjacencyList[vertex_a].append(vertex_b)
    self.adjacencyList[vertex_b].append(vertex_a)

def remove_edge(self, vertex_a, vertex_b):
    self.adjacencyList[vertex_a].remove(vertex_b)
    self.adjacencyList[vertex_b].remove(vertex_a)
    return True

def remove_vertex(self, vertex):
    cities = self.adjacencyList[vertex]
    for city in cities:
        self.remove_edge(vertex, city)
    self.adjacencyList.pop(vertex, None)
    return True
```

And this my main code:

```
graph = Graph()
graph.add_vertex("mexico")
graph.add_vertex("china")
graph.add_vertex("japon")
graph.add_edge("mexico", "china")
graph.add_edge("japon", "mexico")
graph.add_edge("japon", "china")
graph.remove_vertex("japon") # This is where the error occurs
```

So when I call the last function the class method remove vertex only removes the edges from the vertex to remove and the first city it has a connection, such as "mexico" but it doesnt remove the second or others because the loop it breaks here in the for x in arr.

```
def remove_vertex(self, vertex):
cities = self.adjacencyList[vertex] # Cities is an array ["mexico", "japan"]
for city in cities: 
    self.remove_edge(vertex, city)
self.adjacencyList.pop(vertex, None)
return True
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate through this for loop:

```
for city in cities: 
    self.remove_edge(vertex, city)
```

You change the list `cities` *while you are iterating through it*.

Python starts at the first element of `cities`. It removes "mexico" from `cities`. Python then moves to the next element of `cities`. It finds there is no second element, so it exits the for loop - even though it has not iterated through the others.

What you want to do is make a copy of `self.adjacencyList[vertex]`, and iterate through the copy:

```
def remove_vertex(self, vertex):
    cities = self.adjacencyList[vertex].copy()
    for city in cities:
        self.remove_edge(vertex, city)
    self.adjacencyList.pop(vertex, None)
    print(self.adjacencyList) # prints {'mexico': ['china'], 'china': ['mexico']}
    return True
```